# Autocomplete value are not being set on the state or maybe just on the autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Autocomplete value are not being set on the state or maybe just on the autocomplete. When I select a value from the autocomplete after selecting a value when I click on a blank spot or anywhere else my selected value is gone. I didn't check the state value so maybe the value is set on the state but not being on the autocomplete.

**CodeSandbox :** https://codesandbox.io/s/great-butterfly-qgmcr?file=/src/Demo.js:910-922

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  mT: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  }
});

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      accname: ""
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const top100Films = [
      { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
      { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }
    ];

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <Autocomplete
                options={top100Films}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                style={{ minWidth: 200, display: "inline-flex" }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Account Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                )}
                className={classes.mT}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.accname}
                size="small"
                color="primary"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Demo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `onChange` method like below,

```
onChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ accname: value });
  };
```

Complete Code:-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  mT: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  }
});

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      accname: ""
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ accname: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const top100Films = [
      { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
      { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 }
    ];

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
              <Autocomplete
                options={top100Films}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                style={{ minWidth: 200, display: "inline-flex" }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Account Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                )}
                className={classes.mT}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.accname}
                size="small"
                color="primary"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Demo);
```

Code Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mcnulty-9z2de?file=/src/Demo.js